# Synchronize Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm in a codeigniter environment and I want to do something like this.
There is a chatroom with a single O-wner and some C-lients.
This is what I'm trying to write

1) C joins the room.

2) when ready, all Cs clicks on a "ready" link that sends an ajax request

3) C waits for all the Cs to get ready, then signals all client and the previous ajax reponses are sent

4) when C receive the response (which should be in the same moments for all the clients) they start doing what-they-have-to-do :)

Is there an easy way to keep track of all the clients connected so that I can signal them all simultaneously?

For now I'm stuck at step 3. I have a code like this

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'myurl.php',
success: function() { doStuff(); }
});
```

and in my hypotethic file myurl.php i have

```
while ($this -> MyModel -> waitingQueue) {
sleep(1) }
return "ok";
```

I guess this is not a good approach since I can't control whether all the clients receive the responses in the very same instane, when I change in my model the variable "waitingQueue".

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mimic synchronisation with a regular ajax check from all clients on a server. Check the jQuery.queue function, start a queue polling with SetInterval, and then push function containg the checks in that queue (and in theses functions flush the queue).

If you want to go one step further you should get a look at 'Comet' and persitent HTTP connections, trying to put PUSH behavior in HTTP, but it won't be simple :-) At least if you get the complete control of your network, server, people connecting to your app (like an intranet) it will be simplier.

Or you can check documentations on the now closed project google waves.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using [setInterval()](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/window.htm#1203669) in javascript. so you can check continuously for server state.

i don't think you can synchronize your clients that simple. and they will not get the answer from the server at the same time.

if you synchronize the watches of all clients and arrange a collective point in time, when the client shell trigger an event, you might get a good chance.

...and don't forget [clearInterval()](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/window.htm#1201732)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Imagine that all the clients are in the same room in a house (that's the purpose of the app), I guess that even without synchronizing the time, they will receive the answer at the same time (maybe will be just a matter of milliseconds)..

Comment: right, could work. if everyone uses the same browser and similar systems.